# How to process huge data in hbase by modifying org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

My hbase table contains millions of rows. If we do a scan it takes at least an hour to show all the records. We are storing date as row keys. I need to get the min and max values of date. I saw a utility org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter which counts millions of rows in 5 mins. Is there any way to my job in same way?. FYI: I am using java.

Comment: Have you looked at Phoenix, it supports secondary indices? In your case, a covered secondary index with date at the beginning of the key might be a good match. The writes will be amplified however.

Comment: There is no need to perform a full scan of the table. I added an answer on how I would do this, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using HBase 0.98, your problem should be easy. All you have to do is to obtain the first and the last row in your table(since the entries are ordered):

- The first row you obtain by performing a *scan* with the limit of 1.
- The last row you obtain by performing a *reverse scan* with the limit
  of 1.

You can find more information about the *reverse scan* here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4811

If you are using a previous version of HBase then you should considering using some model/convention for your table. The first row is easy to obtain(again just a scan on the table with the limit of 1), but for the last row you do not have the *reverse scan* feature unfortunately.

1. You can design to have an "upside-down" table as described here: http://staltz.blogspot.com/2012/05/first-and-last-rows-in-hbase-table.html
2. Since you are using date as row-key there might be high chances that you might not receive the data in a descending order manner(see the blog post on item 1.), therefore you can keep a secondary table on which you always keep the minimum and maximum values of the date(also implies that you have to perform a check in your code for every record you insert/delete and update your secondary table.
3. Redesign the way you store the data. A suggestion would be to keep your initial table plus a reverse-index table and in your reverse index table to store the data(on the rowkey) such as: MAX_INTEGER - dataTimestamp, therefore the latest date will be your first entry on your reverse table and you retrieve it with a scan(with the limit of 1).

Since the solution for the HBase 0.98 is very simple and no need to make workarounds, in case you do not have that version I would recommend to do a migration.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right direction. The RowCounter usage is the efficient way to count Hbase rows, which has millions of records. You can get the source code of RowCounter and tweak a bit to achieve your requirement

1. Rowcounter will perform scan internally. Then why is it running fast, is because of parellelism in Map reduce. Now once you have scan, I thought, you can always keep filter. So you can identify that piece of code and add filter to it.
2. Now with the above change, your rowcounter will count the rows, which match that filter criteria. To extend it may be, you can parameterize, column family, column qualifier, value, operator etc.

I hope it helps your cause